# how to install gcc4.6.4 on red hat6.4

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat, make-install

When I want to install gcc 4.6.4  (now gcc 4.4.7)

```
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [_muldi3.o] error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/chestnuts/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libgcc'
make[4]: *** [multi-do] error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/chestnuts/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[3]: *** [all-multi] error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/chestnuts/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libgcc] error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/chestnuts/objdir'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble]error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chestnuts/objdir'
```

my step:

```
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..

mkdir obj && cd obj
../gcc-4.7.4/configure 
make && make install
```

Comment: Either install the 32 bit version of glibc-devel or `--disable-multilib`. By the way, why not install a more recent version while you are at it? 4.9.2 is good if you don't want the bleeding-edge 5.1.0.